# AngularJS - ng-click not working in simple Popup

Tags: jquery, angularjs, popup

as my question the problem is with ng-click there is my code:

```
   <div class="top-login"><a href="" class="register">S'inscrire</a></div>
   <div class="in-login"><a href="" class="login">Se connecter</a></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.login").simplePopup({ type: "html", htmlSelector: "#popup1" });
    $("a.register").simplePopup({ type: "html", htmlSelector: "#popup2" });
});
```

and  i test with this example but still not working

```
<div id="popup2" style="display:none;" >
     <div class="col-md-7" ng-controller="RegisterCtrl">
            ok is here:{{ok}}
            <button  class="cws-button2 " type="button"  ng-click="ok=1" >S'inscrire</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

ng-click not working but there is no error

Comment: See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q88t9tvL/) it does work.. what's your scenario?

Comment: @anoop yes it works like the Fiddle but when it will a popup it doesn't work

Comment: can you make fiddle, or modify mine ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q88t9tvL/3/ i modified your Fiddle i hope you understand what i want when  click in <a> a popup displayed but when i click in button signup (with ng-click) nothing happened

Comment: it meant tobe not work like this, don't mix jquery with angular. the controller never bootstraps for your popup div. Try to remove ` style="display:none;"` and see angular is only bound to initial popup html. not to other runtime htmls. So donot use jquery just build your popup with angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because of a scope inheritance issue. See this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

In order to make it work, make ok a property of an object. For example, `ng-click="foo.ok=1"`

Another solution would be to use a function, and do everything in the controller.

```
<button  class="cws-button2 " type="button"  ng-click="doStuff(1)" >S'inscrire</button>
```

And in your controller, declare a function doStuff.

```
$scope.doStuff = function (val) {
    $scope.ok = 1;
};
```

Comment: thanks for you reply but i am new new in angularjs , if there is a problem with scope why when i do this { <input type="text" name="Nom"  placeholder="Nom"  ng-model="user.u_lastname" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="form-row form-row-first">} it works correctly in deed the real function is  <button  class="cws-button2 " type="button"  ng-click="signup()" >S'inscrire</button>  so how can i related it with an object

Comment: That one probably works because you're using ng-model on an object's property. (user is the object, u_lastname is the property). If you refactor your code like I mentioned above, it should work.